# Possible ways to keep track of dynamic ip address?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, lan, wan

So for those who knows what bitcoin miner is I got one, for those who don't know what it is they can search to see what i mean.

Anyway as far as I have seen, machine is running and configurable through mikrotik installed on raspberry pi.

And I got it working.

The problem is that machine is located on my friend's house, and I need access to the machine from time to time. So far I have made redirect on router so machine is accessible to outside world.

But I can access it only if I know what is ip address of my friend internet. But as he have dynamic ip address, the address is changing from time to time, and I can't access the machine unless he tells me the new address.

What are the possible ways to track dynamic ip address and know what is the address when it's changed so I can access machine any time?

Answer (score 4):

You can access your external ip address formatted as simple text from http://wtfismyip.com/text. You can write a shell script to 'wget' the address and 'mail' it to you. The 'crond' on your raspberry pi can then regularly execute the script.

Comment: This is basically what i have in mind, i just don't know how to do it :)

Comment: Something like this should work:inline `#!/bin/sh
    wget  http://wtfismyip.com/text -O /tmp/myip.txt
    myip=`cat /tmp/myip.txt`
    echo "my ip is $myip"
    
    SUBJECT="My ip is $myip"
    EMAIL="your@your.domain"
    echo "Put whatever you want here" > /tmp/mailbody.txt
    mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < /tmp/mailbody.txt`